# Como escrever programas que suportem internacionalização usando cmake?

Tags: c++, i18n, cmake

Estou escrevendo um pequeno software em c++ e gostaria de poder traduzi-lo para outras línguas.
Olhando rapidamente pela internet a ferramenta mais aceita em ambientes linux é o `GNU gettext`.

Na documentação oficial do projeto Gnome tem [este link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-internationalization-intro.html.en) dando alguns passos de como inicializar a ferramenta.

Uma parte da explicação é muito boa e bastante óbvia porem fiquei com algumas dúvidas pelo caminho.

1. Como eu inicializo o intl/gettext com o cmake? Geralmente eu apenas adiciono as bibliotecas que eu preciso no meu `CMakeLists.txt`, mas no link acima eles utilizam um script em shell.
2. Qual a finalidade do comando `intltoolize`?
3. Eu fiquei um pouco confuso com o arquivo `POTFILES.in`. Se a tradução é feita em run-time, qual a finalidade de listar os arquivos que tem algo a ser traduzido? Quando eu compilar estas referencias serão perdidas de qualquer forma, então porque devo marcá-las?
4. Qual a finalidade dos demais arquivos do intl (`intltool-extract.in`, `intltool-merge.in` e `intltool-update.in`?

Não sei se isso ajuda, mas alguns detalhes do projeto:

- Estou usando g++
- A linguagem alvo é o c++17
- Já está incluso no meu projeto a biblioteca `gtkmm`, portanto não sei se preciso incluir mais dependências para usar o `gettext`.

Answer (score -1):

O GNU gettext é uma biblioteca que permite que os desenvolvedores criem aplicativos que possam ser facilmente traduzidos para outros idiomas. Ele fornece ferramentas para extrair cadeias de caracteres que precisam ser traduzidas e gerar arquivos de tradução.

Para inicializar o uso do gettext com o CMake, você pode usar o módulo FindGettext, que está disponível na maioria das distribuições de CMake. Você pode usar o comando find_package(Gettext) em seu CMakeLists.txt para encontrar a biblioteca. Se a biblioteca não estiver disponível, você precisará instalá-la em seu sistema.

O comando intltoolize é usado para inicializar um diretório com arquivos de modelo e scripts para a internacionalização de um projeto. Ele cria um arquivo configure.in e um diretório po com vários arquivos. Isso permite que você use as ferramentas gettext para extrair cadeias de caracteres que precisam ser traduzidas e gerar arquivos de tradução.

O arquivo POTFILES.in é um arquivo que lista os arquivos do projeto que contêm cadeias de caracteres que precisam ser traduzidas. Isso ajuda a automatizar o processo de extração das cadeias de caracteres que precisam ser traduzidas, permitindo que você atualize facilmente os arquivos de tradução quando as cadeias de caracteres mudarem.

Os arquivos intltool-extract.in, intltool-merge.in e intltool-update.in são scripts que são usados pelas ferramentas gettext para extrair cadeias de caracteres que precisam ser traduzidas, mesclar arquivos de tradução e atualizar arquivos de tradução existentes.

É possível usar o gettext com a biblioteca gtkmm. Você não precisa incluir nenhuma dependência adicional para usar o gettext, mas precisará incluir a biblioteca gettext em seu projeto e usar as ferramentas fornecidas para criar arquivos de tradução para o seu aplicativo.

Answer (score -2):

Vamos esclarecer suas dúvidas em relação ao uso do GNU gettext no CMake para internacionalização do seu software em C++:

Inicialização do intl/gettext com CMake:
Para integrar o GNU gettext ao seu projeto C++ usando o CMake, você pode usar o módulo FindGettext do CMake. Adicione o seguinte trecho ao seu CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Gettext REQUIRED)
```

Em seguida, você pode usar as variáveis geradas pelo módulo, como ${GETTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR} e ${GETTEXT_LIBRARIES}, em seus alvos. Por exemplo:

```
target_include_directories(seu_alvo PUBLIC ${GETTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(seu_alvo ${GETTEXT_LIBRARIES})
```

Finalidade do comando intltoolize:
O comando intltoolize é usado para inicializar o ambiente de internacionalização para seu projeto. Ele copia arquivos necessários e configura a estrutura de diretórios para suportar as ferramentas de internacionalização. Geralmente, você executa este comando uma vez no início do desenvolvimento do seu projeto.

Arquivo POTFILES.in:
O arquivo POTFILES.in lista os arquivos fonte que contêm as strings a serem traduzidas. Ele é utilizado para gerar o arquivo POT (Portable Object Template) que servirá como base para as traduções. Mesmo que as traduções sejam feitas em runtime, é necessário identificar as strings a serem traduzidas durante o processo de construção.

Outros arquivos do intl (intltool-extract.in, intltool-merge.in e intltool-update.in):
Esses arquivos são scripts utilizados pelo intltool para realizar tarefas específicas, como extrair mensagens para tradução, mesclar traduções e atualizar os arquivos PO (Portable Object) com base no arquivo POT. Eles são parte do conjunto de ferramentas do intltool e são utilizados durante o processo de internacionalização.

Dependências adicionais para usar o gettext com gtkmm:
Se você já está usando a biblioteca gtkmm, e ela não possui dependências adicionais para suportar o gettext, então você não precisa adicionar mais dependências. O gettext é geralmente independente das bibliotecas gráficas como gtkmm.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).